# delete whole couchbase lite db issue

Tags: java, android, couchbase-lite

I wanna delete my entire `Couchbase lite DB`, but for some reasons some records won't be deleted, I tried the following code:

```
try{ db.delete()} catch{...}
```

but it won't work,
it seems like `SQLite` got some problems with old indexes,
with something like:

> revisionId has already existed...

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Revision id should refer to a document, not a database.  Can you post a full code example of the create, delete, create sequence?  Also, what happens if you try to reopen the database but don't allow creating it if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

first stop replication and then delete DB

```
public void stopReplication() {
    if (mPull != null) {
        mPull.stop();
    }
    if (mPush != null) {
        mPush.stop();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "stopReplication: success");
}

public boolean deleteAllDocuments() {
    try {
        mDatabase.close();
        mDatabase.delete();
        mDatabase = null;
        mManager = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "deleteAllDocuments: success");
        return true;
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "deleteAllDocuments: Failed to close and delete database.");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "deleteAllDocuments: Failed to close and delete database.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

happy coding... :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use following steps
1.Delete database
2.Close database manager
3.Assign database to null

code:-

```
try {
     myDatabase.delete();
     myDatabase.manager(close);
     myDatabase = null;
} catch (IOExcept`enter code here`ion e) {
     Log.e(TAG, "Cannot delete database", e);
     return;
}
```

Comment: Not working for me.Even if i do the above things, on next sign in I am getting previous signed in user documents.Any idea? Please help.